# Material UI Individual Icons

Tags: svg, import, material-ui, icons

I was wondering whether it is possible to download individual icons from the MUI package to store as svgs in an app's folder. The reason behind this is to improve the performance and external packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible as long as each Icon from MUI icons package doesn't provide its own npm package.

You better use https://fonts.google.com/icons to download svgs then use them in [SVGIcon](https://mui.com/components/icons/#svgicon) component.

also you can see this [MUI doc page about tree shaking](https://mui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/) this can be useful to reduce bundle size and improve performance in the same way.